# Add a tracking category to a page in a MediaWiki extension **not** using a parser function

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want to add a tracking category to specific pages on my wiki, running MW 1.24. I know that I can do so using either Parser::addTrackingCategory() or ParserOptions::addCategory(), but the only example I can find of using them is from within a parser function (as seen in extension:Maps, for example), which I'm **not** using.

The extension I use is [ApprovedRevs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Approved_Revs)-derived; basically what it does is assign a page to a project, and allows a simple approval. This is all done outside of the actual page content (additional database tables), so there's no parser function / tag.

I've tried using quite a few hooks: ParserAfterTidy, ContentGetParserOutput, OutputPageParserOutput and a few others. While the first at least shows the category on page, the page isn't actually included in the tracking category (which displays as empty).

My code (abbr.) is something like this:

```
$wgTrackingCategories[] = 'approvedrevs-tracking-category';
$wgHooks['ParserAfterTidy'][] = 'onParserAfterTidy';

public static function onParserAfterTidy( Parser&$parser, &$text ) {
  $title = $parser->getTitle();
  if( ApprovedRevs:isPageAssigned( $title ) {
    $parser->addTrackingCategory( 'approvedrevs-tracking-category' );
  }
}
```

I added the appropriate messages for this tracking category; at this point, I can see the categories on page, and I can see the tracking category listed at `Special:TrackingCategories`.

I did find now that starting with MW 1.25, there's an additional hook named [ContentAlterParserOutput](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ContentAlterParserOutput), used for example in [Extension:CommonsMetadata](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommonsMetadata), which seems to allow exactly that - but I'm still limited to MediaWiki 1.24... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The commit](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/161471/) adding ContentAlterParserOutput explains how it differs from other hooks, and also outlines some workarounds. (Commits adding a hook or setting are usually linked from the manual page and are generally worth a click.)

So ParserAfterTidy should work, although you will run into trouble with it being called on all kinds of things which are not part of the page content. Try doing a null edit on the page and see if the category is updated.

An example of an extension adding tracking categories from a similar hook (ParserBeforeTidy) is [Cite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cite).

Comment: At the end, I decided that patching my version of MediaWiki (until 1.25 is released) is much easier and makes more sense than using unstable workarounds - especially since this is a very contained patch. Patching MW core isn't something that I would recommend for a public-intended extension, but something I'm fine with for our enterprise use.

Comment: @DrorS. no it's not fine. It will make your upgrades more painful, which will reduce the chances you'll upgrade at all, which will make your company less safe.

Comment: @Nemo, while I don't generally condone patching core, it made more sense to make a temporary change, easily reverted on upgrade, then use an unsatisfactory workaround in my code. And anyway, I just mentioned it here for completeness. Please keep in mind this is a developers' website - so if I think I can handle a small contained patch, then I probably can...